# AWS API for whether a video is available on Prime instant video

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to find a way to see if the AWS API can tell whether a movie is available on Prime instant videos.

Based on the thread here on AWS developer forums:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93283

It seems like there's a Amazon Prime Instant Videos node (2676882011)
However, trying something like the following returns results even if a movie isn't available on Prime:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService
&Version=2011-08-01
&Operation=ItemLookup
&ItemId=B000V1Z8KK
&BrowseNode=2676882011
&AssociateTag=xxxxxx
```

The responses in the thread also states that it's unreliable.

Is there a way to check whether a video is available on Prime instant video without having to scrape the page and look for the text pattern?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's really disappointing that there is no way to determine if a product is prime or not.

Comment: It sure is. Unfortunately I don't think Amazon has a plan to support this. I ended up crawling the page and parsing it with Nokogiri to see if it's available on prime. Hope this hacky way helps

Comment: I couldn't find a prime indicator on the product page. Can you fill me in on this?

Answer (score 2):

First, the `ItemLookup` request doesn't support a `BrowseNode` Attribute. Only the `ItemSearch` does. So unfortunatly a `ItemLookup` won't work indeed, but I suppose, you can achieve what you want, using the `ItemSearch` request.

Try the following:

1. Use the amazon movie title. I assume you have access to the movie title? (If not you could make a quick request with the API).
2. Make an `ItemSearch`. `ItemSearch` supports the attribute `Title` which explicitly searches for a certain Title (or parts of it). You can also use the browse node you already found, the "Prime Instant Video"-node (2676882011), using the attribute `BrowseNode`. This way, you only search for items with a specific title in the prime instant video node.
3. Now look at the result: *If it contains items*, **it's prime**, *if it doesn't*, **it's not**.

## Examples

Do a request like:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService
&Version=2013-08-01
&AssociateTag=Foo
&Operation=ItemSearch
&SearchIndex=Video
&BrowseNode=2676882011
&Title=Fargo
```

And the response would contain **one item**: The movie *Fargo [HD]*. This is because **it's in Prime**!

If you alter your request to:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService
&Version=2013-08-01
&AssociateTag=Foo
&Operation=ItemSearch
&SearchIndex=Video
&BrowseNode=2676882011
&Title=Gone+Girl
```

You will get **no items**. *Gone Girl* is available in Amazon Instant Video, but **not in Prime**.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that Amazon doesn't have a plan to support this field in their API. The best way to determine whether a movie is available on Prime is via crawling the page and parsing it to see if it's available on Prime.

The following Xpath would work:

```
//div[@id='dv-side-box-container']//a[contains(@class, 'prime')]
```